# How to formulate "variable free in sign" in Linear programming?

Tags: r, variables, linear-programming

I just tried to formulate dea(data development analysis) in R script. And the LP are in following format:
[Snapshot of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ3yE.jpg)

While I don't know how to set "free-in-sign variable" in package "Rglpk"(which I used to solve the LP in R), I set up two variable to represent u1 and u2 in the model.

```
u1 = u1a - u1b ; u2 = u2a - u2b
```

And my r code to solve this model is shown below:

```
 f.rhs <- c(rep(0,1,2*N),1)   
 f.dir <- c(rep("<=",1,2*N),"==")  
 aux1 <- cbind(-1*X,Z,0*Y,1,-1,0,0)
 aux2 <- cbind(0*X,-1*Z,Y,0,0,1,-1)
    
 for (i in 1:N) { 
    f.obj <- c(rep(0,1,s),as.numeric(Z[i,]),as.numeric(Y[i,]),1,-1,1,-1)
    f.con <- rbind(aux1,aux2,c(as.numeric(X[i,]),as.numeric(Z[i,]),rep(0,1,m+4))) 
    results <- Rglpk_solve_LP(f.obj,f.con,f.dir,f.rhs,max=TRUE)
    }
```

But I didn't get any acceptable results and don't know if there is any problem in my formulation. The outcomes of this model should be in 0~1, but I got a 1.033 and a negative weight in one of the outcome.

Could somebody please guide me how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs of [Rglpk](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rglpk/Rglpk.pdf) shows that **there is a bound-parameter available**.

**Use it! (and don't split)**

- While the split-var-approach should work in general (i did not check your code) it's a bad approach (doubles the amount of variables; possible numerical-instability at least for IPM-based solvers) and more direct-ones are preferred

  - As GLPK is simplex-based (i think there is a not state-of-the-art IPM too, but simplex is probably default) there is a high probability, that there is a more direct handling of these bounds, therefore, use it (by using the bounds-argument)
  - **Defining a variable as free in this case means: set those bounds to -inf, inf**

Something straight from the docs (page 6 of 7; version 0.6-2):

```
## Same as before but with bounds replaced by
## -Inf < x_1 <= 4
## 0 <= x_2 <= 100
## 2 <= x_3 < Inf
bounds <- list(lower = list(ind = c(1L, 3L), val = c(-Inf, 2)),
upper = list(ind = c(1L, 2L), val = c(4, 100)))
Rglpk_solve_LP(obj, mat, dir, rhs, bounds, types, max)
```